# Cmake: Cross generate build systems from Linux possible?

Tags: cmake

Is it possible generate build systems on one platform for another using cmake? For example, and the case I'm most interested in, is it possible to generate a set of Visual Studio solution files, or mingw32-make Makefiles, or nmake files, for a project from Linux?

The intention is to make something analogous to what the `make dist` target produces in automake. However, I don't need it to do as much as `make dist` does, i.e. I just want to generate the solution files as though I'd run cmake in Windows.

Users can then build the package using the created build system on their own machines.

If it is possible, how do I do it? Cmake doesn’t report the Windows based generators as being available on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research I believe the answer to my question is no. The reason is that the makefiles and solution files etc. produced by cmake depend on cmake itself, the path to which is hard-coded into the files.

One solution for windows might be to bundle the cmake executable with your files and replace the definition of CMAKE_COMMAND (for instance) added to makefiles with the path to your bundled version of cmake somehow. This is just a suggestion though, I haven't tried or even researched it much. If you do, please post the process as a comment or answer here.